# Tomcat HTTPS keystore certificate

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https, keystore

Ran into another problem using SSL and Tomcat: I've configured a keystore which contains a key and a certificate (the server certificate I wish to present to the clients connecting to the site). I've done the same for the truststore (I'm going to need client authentication).

The problem I have now is that when I connect to my Tomcat instance via HTTPS, the certificate presented to me (the server certificate) is not my actual server certificate, but rather the **key** in the JKS keystore. Using -Djavax.net.debug=ssl reveals that it's presenting the correct CA for client authentication, but not the correct server certificate.

```
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=A
  Issuer:  CN=A
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: -
  Valid from Tue Nov 10 14:48:31 CET 2009 until Mon Feb 08 14:48:31 CET 2010

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: X
  Issuer:  X
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: -
  Valid from Wed Jan 19 01:00:00 CET 2005 until Mon Jan 19 00:59:59 CET 2015
```

I've replaced the real values with place holders. A = the domain name of the server (but in this case, for some reason this is the key and not the certificate). X = a VeriSign CA (this should be correct). I have an existing certificate I would like to use to present to the clients, which I imported into a JKS keystore using keytool.

The Tomcat connector configuration:

```
<Connector port="444" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
  maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
  clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"     
  keystoreFile="conf/ssl/keystore.jks"
  keystorePass="xx"
  keyAlias="testkey"
  truststoreFile="conf/ssl/truststore.jks"
  truststorePass="xx" />
```

Any idea why my Tomcat instance is not presenting the correct certificate?

Comment: give the ssl connector configuration (from server.xml)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is (apparently - I can not really confirm this) that it's impossible to properly import a previously generated certificate (and matching key) into a JKS keystore and have it presented properly by Tomcat.

The situation in which my problem occurred is as follows:

1. I have a certificate file, which I generated myself using OpenSSL from scratch (key + CSR -> certificate), signed by my own CA.
2. I wish to configure Tomcat so that it presents **this particular certificate** to the users connecting to my site.

The solution I found to work is:

1. Convert the existing certificate **and** its private key to the DER format. For example (using OpenSSL):

   For the *private key*;

   `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in my_private_key.key -inform PEM -out my_private_key.der -outform DER`

   For the actual *signed certificate*;

   `openssl x509 -in my_certificate.crt -inform PEM -out my_certificate.der -outform DER`
2. Import both DER files into a keystore (JKS file) using a custom Java class.

   `java ImportKey my_private_key.der my_certificate.der`

   I did not figure this out myself (all credit goes to the original inventor(s)).The source for this Java class, and some more details can be found [here](http://www.comu.de/docs/tomcat_ssl.htm) and [here](http://www.agentbob.info/agentbob/79-AB.html). I modified this class slightly so that there is a 3rd (or 4th) parameter that specifies the output location of the resulting JKS file.

The end result is a JKS keystore which can then be used in the Tomcat Connector configuration as the keystore. The above tool will generate the JKS file with default passwords for the key and JKS file itself, these can be changed later using `keytool -storepasswd` and `keytool -keypasswd`. Hope this helps for people facing the same issue.

Comment: +1. The second link (agentbob.info) worked for me. It issues a password to the keystore which the first link (comu.de) doesn't. Java's keytool doesn't like to change the password of a keystore that has no password. Also, you can specify the key alias tomcat expects (it's 'tomcat').

Comment: The old `keytool -import`, officially renamed `-importcert` since IIRC j5 ~2005, could not import a private key. You could use `openssl pkcs12 -export` to combine the PEM private key and matching certificate -- and optionally and preferably any needed _chain_ cert as well -- into a PKCS12, which Java itself could read but some programs couldn't use, in which case you could use `keytool -importkeystore -srcstoretype pkcs12 -deststoretype jks ...` to convert to JKS. (Since 8u60 in 2015 nearly all programs accept PKCS12.)

Comment: However Tomcat >= 8.5 (which will soon be the only supported versions) no longer needs a keystore at all, it uses a new config scheme which can use OpenSSL-source PEM files even for JSSE, so this is about to be obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

Your configuration should work correctly.

[Tomcat's how-to](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/ssl-howto.html) explains the steps to take in order to have a proper JKS.

Make sure you have imported the Certificate to the jks, with the appropriate alias (testKey)

Comment: When I set the keyAlias to the alias of the certificate in the keystore, Tomcat won't boot correctly. I'm assuming the keyAlias parameters is used to specify the key, not the certificate.

I get a feeling that Tomcat will never properly present my certificate, because it was created separately. Right now I'm going to try to generate a brand new certificate from scratch using keytool instead of openssl, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: yes, try that. The key and the certificate, as it can be seen in the tomcat how-to, are to be under the same alias.

Comment: My previous attempt failed. I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what. Is it even possible to present an existing certificate, or do you have to use keytool to generate a new one? This is confusing.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is identical to the following issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180397/tomcat-server-client-self-signed-ssl-certificate. Only, I don't want to generate a new certificate, I want to use an existing one.

Comment: the general flow is this - you generate a Key an a CSR, then based on that CSR you get a certificate (either by yourself, or from VeriSign/GeoTrust/etc.) and import it.

Comment: I have done that, generated a key and CSR using keytool, signed it with my own CA using OpenSSL, and then imported the signed certificate back into the keystore. Using this keystore, Tomcat still sends the keyEntry and not the trustedCertificate entry for some reason.

Comment: Could it be that it's not presenting the certificate because the CA with which it was signed is not a part of the truststore?

Comment: I've figured it out - I'll answer my question soon when I get some free time (I've already wasted too much time on this :D).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @Bozho comment,

This was really critical. **"The key and the purchased certificate are to be under the same alias"**.

The SSL certificate bought from the CA (Verisign, Digicert etc.) should be imported with the same alias as the private key generated before creating the csr. After importing the purchased certificate into the keystore using java keytool, you will see **"Certificate reply added to keystore".**

To check the trust chain, use the terminal command **openssl s_client -connect yourdomain.com:443 -showcerts.** It starts at your cert and leads to up to a trusted root CA.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the commands to generate a proper certificate entry for a keystore. Background knowledge: since Tomcat version 7, Tomcat supports PKCS12 as a keystore format, and java keystores can readily import such files. More background knowledge: key entries in keystores require the entire certificate chain to be present, or else SSL errors will happen.

So here's what to do:

1. concatenate your intermediate (signing root) cert and your root CA cert together:

   cat intermediate.pem root.pem > chain.pem
2. concatenate your signed certificate with the chain:

   cat cert.pem chain.pem > fullchain.pem
3. Now, create a pkcs12 file with the full chain, and the roots clearly identified. Make sure to copy the private key you generated with your CSR (named privkey.pem in my example) is in the same dir as the other files you generated when you execute this command::

   openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out keystore.p12 -name server -CAfile chain.pem -caname root
4. Okay, cool; this file should work fine. You could just copy this to conf/ssl and modify your server.xml to use keystore.p12 instead of keystore.jks. Or, you could import it into your keystore file by cding to conf/ssl and running this command (maybe make a backup first):

   keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -alias server