# Can the alias in a keystore be a guid?

Tags: ssl, tomcat6, keytool

I have a problem in regards to Tomcat 6 and certificates. The problem is somewhat similar to this: [Tomcat HTTPS keystore certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055314/tomcat-https-keystore-certificate).

My task is to get a Jira installation running with an SSL certificate issued by a CA.

To make sure I have got the workflow right I have tried to create a certificate of my own the following way (this works):

- Create 'my' keystore
- Extract the certificate from the 'my' keystore
- Import the extracted certificate into Java's \cacerts keystore.

This solution works fine - site can be accessed over SSL.

I assume the following can be done with my CA issued certificate, in the form of a pfx file.

I created a new keystore using this command:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore certificate.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore \mydest\keystore.jks -deststorepass changeit
```

When I list the contents of the new keystore.jks I get one entry; private key with a guid.

I extract the certificate from the keystore. **In this operation I am unable to specify an alias**.

I import the certificate into the \cacerts keystore.

I then list the concents of the \cacerts keystore and find my new entry. Instead of having a name, the entry is showing the same guid as from the initial (pfx) keystore.

I alter my server.xml file with the new alias (e.g. guid) and keystore file.

However - starting Tomcat gives this error:

> Alias name {guid} does not identify a key entry

Question is:

1. Can a guid be a key name?
2. If not, what I am doing wrong? :)

I have tried both keystores in the server.xml file, without luck.

New info; when I execute this command I am able to find information regarding the certificate in the \cacerts file:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore \cacerts -alias {guid}
```

So it seems that the guid exists. However, Tomcat seems to be unable to find the same key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is 'yes'.

The origins of my problem was that I had the wrong password for the key from the pfx file. Using the following command I changed the password from the original one to a the standard password (I did this prior to exporting the certificate from the keystore created from the pfx file):

```
keytool -keypasswd -alias {guid}
```

Keytool then asked me for old password and new password.

I might have been able to add some sort of configuration in the server.xml file like 'keypassword', but I haven't looked into that.