# Tomcat with client certificate and Grails

Tags: tomcat, grails, ssl-certificate

I found the right information on how to configure tomcat with client certificates on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180397/tomcat-server-client-self-signed-ssl-certificate), configured my tomcat, deployed a grails application and searched within the grails application for the client certificate. I found it in the property

```
request.request.request.attributes['javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate']
```

Is this the right way to access the certificate? Is looks a bit wrong :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. I think I've got it... this looks better:

```
request['javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate']
```