# Fix "The certificate is self-signed." error in Tomcat server with an SSL from Godaddy

Tags: tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I just installed an SSL certificate in my tomcat (running in Windows 8) signed by GoDaddy, but when I run this tool http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html I receive this error:

> The certificate is self-signed. Users will receive a warning when accessing this site unless the certificate is manually added as a trusted certificate to their web browser. You can fix this error by buying a trusted SSL certificate.

I chat with GoDaddy and they told I have to delete the self-signed certificate.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you show your connector config from server.xml?

Comment: GoDaddy Support: [SSL Certificate Renewal - Tomcat 4.x/5.x/6.x](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5355/ssl-certificate-renewal-tomcat-4-x5-x6-x). Also see [How to import GoDaddy certificates in Tomcat given gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt, gdig2.crt & mydomain.crt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269293/how-to-import-godaddy-certificates-in-tomcat-given-gd-bundle-g2-g1-crt-gdig2-cr).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180397/tomcat-server-client-self-signed-ssl-certificate?rq=1