# Apache configuration vhost HTTPS ( ERROR CODE 500) - owncloud

Tags: php, apache, apache2, lamp, opensuse

I'm trying to configure owncloud service on my VPS using HTTPS connection.

Unfortunately I receive error 500.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator if this error reappears multiple times, please include the technical details below in your report.
More details can be found in the server log.
```

From error_log:

```
[Wed May 18 20:19:35.288249 2016] [ssl:info] [pid 22473] [client 89.187.231.134:59370] AH01964: Connection to child 1 established (server owncloud.XXX.cloud:443)
[Wed May 18 20:19:35.288517 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 22473] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1928): [client 89.187.231.134:59370] AH02044: No matching SSL virtual host for servername own.XXX.cloud found (using default/first virtual host)
[Wed May 18 20:19:35.357846 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 22473] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1854): [client 89.187.231.134:59370] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
[Wed May 18 20:19:35.421707 2016] [ssl:info] [pid 22473] (70014)End of file found: [client 89.187.231.134:59370] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
[Wed May 18 20:19:35.421924 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 22473] ssl_engine_io.c(1003): [client 89.187.231.134:59370] AH02001: Connection closed to child 1 with standard shutdown (server owncloud.XXX.cloud:443)
[Wed May 18 20:19:35.487962 2016] [ssl:info] [pid 22474] [client 89.187.231.134:59371] AH01964: Connection to child 2 established (server owncloud.XXX.cloud:443)
[Wed May 18 20:19:35.488336 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 22474] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1928): [client 89.187.231.134:59371] AH02044: No matching SSL virtual host for servername own.XXX.cloud found (using default/first virtual host)
[Wed May 18 20:19:35.558679 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 22474] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1854): [client 89.187.231.134:59371] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
[Wed May 18 20:19:35.628110 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 22474] ssl_engine_kernel.c(244): [client 89.187.231.134:59371] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 2 (server owncloud.XXX.cloud:443)
[Wed May 18 20:19:35.628431 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 22474] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 89.187.231.134:59371] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Wed May 18 20:19:35.628539 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 22474] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 89.187.231.134:59371] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Wed May 18 20:19:35.689656 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 22474] ssl_engine_io.c(1003): [client 89.187.231.134:59371] AH02001: Connection closed to child 2 with standard shutdown (server owncloud.XXX.cloud:443)
```

from access_log:

```
89.187.YYY.ZZZ - - [18/May/2016:20:23:05 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 500 289 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
```

My vhost file:

```
owncloud:/etc/apache2/vhosts.d # cat owncloud.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>

#### Redirect to port 443 ###
RewriteEngine on
ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
#### End of Redirection configuration ###

DocumentRoot /srv/www/htdocs/owncloud/
<Directory /srv/www/htdocs/owncloud/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

####Configuration for SSL #####
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/owncloud.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/owncloud.key
#### End of SSL Configuration ####

DocumentRoot /srv/www/htdocs/owncloud/
<Directory /srv/www/htdocs/owncloud/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Loaded modules:

```
owncloud:/etc/apache2/vhosts.d # apache2ctl -M
[Wed May 18 20:28:37.076507 2016] [so:warn] [pid 22581] AH01574: module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 systemd_module (static)
 php5_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
```

My OS:

```
owncloud:/srv/www/htdocs/owncloud # cat /etc/issue
Welcome to openSUSE Leap 42.1 - Kernel \r (\l).
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180397/tomcat-server-client-self-signed-ssl-certificate

Comment: I'm not shure if this solution is OK for me. I don't use Tomcat. Of course i can generate key store, but probably I'cant use it with apache without convert it to standard ssl keyfile.